# What is meant by stack in connection to a process?

Tags: process, java, process-management, multithreading

From the book [Advanced programming in the Unix environment](http://techbus.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/unix/0201433079/unix-system-overview/ch01lev1sec3?reader=html&imagepage=)  I read the following line regarding threads in Unix like systems

> All the threads within a process share the same address space, ﬁle
>   descriptors, stacks, and process-related attributes.Because they can
>   access the same memory,the threads need to synchronize access to
>   shared data among themselves to avoid inconsistencies.

What does the author mean by `stacks` here ? I do Java programming and know each thread gets its own stack . So I am confused by **shared** `stacks` concept here .

Comment: Have a look at wikipedia articels on [Stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and [Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computer_science)) to get a general idea of how things work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the context of a Unix or linux process, the phrase "the stack" can mean two things.

First, "the stack" can mean the last-in, first-out records of the calling sequence of the flow of control. When a process executes, `main()` gets called first. `main()` might call `printf()`. Code generated by the compiler writes the address of the format string, and any other arguments to `printf()` to some memory locations. Then the code writes the address to which flow-of-control should return after `printf()` finishes.  Then the code calls a jump or branch to the start of `printf()`.  Each thread has one of these function activation record stacks.  Note that a lot of CPUs have hardware instructions for setting up and maintaining the stack, but that other CPUs (IBM 360, or whatever it's called) actually used linked lists that could potentially be scattered about the address space.

Second, "the stack" can mean the memory locations to which the CPU writes arguments to functions, and the address that a called-function should return to. "The stack" refers to a contiguous piece of the process' address space.

Memory in a Unix or Linux or *BSD process is a very long line, starting at about 0x400000, and ending at about 0x7fffffffffff (on x86_64 CPUs). The stack address space starts at the largest numerical address. Every time a function gets called, the stack of function activatio records "grows down": the process code puts function arguments and a return address on the stack of activatio records, and decrements the stack pointer, a special CPU register used to keep track of where in the address space of the stack, the process current variables' values reside.

Each thread gets a piece of "the stack" (stack address space) for its own use as a function activation record stack. Somewhere between 0x7fffffffffff and a lower address, each thread has an area of memory reserved for use in function calls.  Usually this is only enforced by convention, not hardware, so if your thread calls function after nested function, the bottom of that thread's stack can overwrite the top of another thread's stack.

So each thread has a piece of "the stack" memory area, and that's where the "shared stack" terminology comes from. It's a consequence of a process address space being a single linear chunk of memory, and the two uses of the term "the stack".  I'm pretty sure that some older JVMs (really ancient) in reality only had a single thread. Any threading inside the Java code was really done by a single real thread. Newer JVMs, JVMs who invoke real threads to do Java threads, will have the same "shared stack" I describe above.  Linux and Plan 9 have a process-starting system call (clone() for Linux, rfork() in Plan 9) that can set up processes that share parts of the address space, and maybe different stack address spaces, but that style of threading never really caught on.

Comment: The stack doesn't necessarily need to grow down, that is architecture dependent. Memory addresses really start at 0x0, the question is what virtual addresses are mappable - the lowest pages often are not to prevent NULL pointer dereference hitting a valid page.

Comment: It is not true that *native* thread stacks are taken from some "main stack" of the process -- that implies the process arranges all this, which it does not.  The kernel does, and it provides a *separate stack for each thread*, including the first one (which is not subsequently "divided up").

Comment: @peterph - You make good points, but can you name an architecture other than HP's PA-RISC that has a stack that grows up? Section 2.3.2 of "Thirty Years Later: Lessons learned from the Multics Security Evaluation" (http://www.acsac.org/2002/papers/classic-multics.pdf) implies that Multics hardware had such a stack.

Comment: @BruceEdiger check [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664744/what-is-the-direction-of-stack-growth-in-most-modern-systems) for some interesting reading. In additionn to that I believe for example on DEC Alphas stack grew - not sure if I can say "has grown" :) - up as well.

Comment: @goldilocks by *native* you mean those that are implemented as separated kernel processes/tasks sharing some virtual memory mapping (all but thread local stuff)?

Comment: @peterph - Thanks for the tip for the SO article, but it's completely wrong for SPARC.  The SPARC had a circular buffer of registers, 32 of which were available at any one time, but "the stack" was just like an x86 stack, except that the stack pointer was 96 bytes below any local variables. The compiler would generate code to spill the register window to the stack if necessary.  I'm pretty sure that my old DEC UDB had a stack that grew down, however.

Comment: @peterph: I mean what most people generally mean when they refer to execution threads. They are not separate processes, but they are managed in kernel space (as opposed to "green" threads  which are userland emulations of such) so maybe separate tasks there.  All modern OS's have native threads; a pthreads implementation wraps whatever system calls are necessary to do this -- eg, in linux `clone()` is the basis of that, which is also the basis of `fork()`, and thus of all processes and threads.

Comment: Also: the stack is actually *last in, first out*.

Comment: The stack does not necessarily start at the highest address, especially if there are more than one ( for each thread ).  Each thread gets its own stack, not divide up one.  Also arguments often are passed in registers, not on the stack, especially on x86_64 since it has more registers than i386.  Also only *local* variables are placed on the stack.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the author mean by stacks here ? I do Java programming and
>   know each thread gets its own stack . So I am confused by shared
>   stacks concept here.

The use of the plural there is a bit odd and it does seem misleading, perhaps the point is that the multiple stacks of a multi-threaded program share the same address space.

As Bruce Ediger describes, "stack" refers to a single region of contiguous address space in which data is placed LIFO-wise.  However, *each native thread* in a process has such a contiguous region -- there is not one divided up between each of them.  Creating a thread *does require the allocation of an additional stack* of the same size (this is a fixed number, eg. the default on linux is 8 MB), which is why excessively multi-threaded applications can consume excessive amounts of memory.

Java uses native threads to implement java threads, but it manages a "stack" for each of the java threads itself, independent of the kernel.  This means setting some global memory aside to use for this purpose; see the third part of the top answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483047/why-is-creating-a-thread-said-to-be-expensive

Of course, that refers to a specific implementation (openjdk), but presumably they all have to do this (allocate heap natively for internal use as a "thread stack").

Since the individual stack used by each native thread is managed by the kernel, I disagree with Bruce's implication that this is part of some overall stack belonging to the process as a whole -- again, a single (aka non-) threaded process only has one stack, but the main thread in a multi-threaded process **does not** share stack space with the other threads.

A "shared stack" would be one in which all data is stored beginning with a single address -- this is the sense in which nested function calls share the same stack.  However, using a tweaked version of an example program mentioned below by Bruce, from the linux version of the [pthread_create man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) man page:

```
./a.out one two three
In main() stack starts near: 0x7fff17b80f98
Thread 1: top of stack near 0x7f11ac6d3e78; argv_string=one
Thread 2: top of stack near 0x7f11abed2e78; argv_string=two
Thread 3: top of stack near 0x7f11ab6d1e78; argv_string=three
```

This program takes the address of a local variable in the threaded function; the tweak I added was to do the same thing in `main()` before the threads are created. The run is on a recent 64-bit linux system; notice the starting addresses for the threads are EXACTLY 8 MB apart, and they are very far indeed from the top of the main thread stack.  Contrast this with nested function calls like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void eg (int n) {
    char *p;
    printf("#%d first variable at %p\n", n, &p);
    if (n < 3) eg(n+1);
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    char *p;
    printf("main() first variable at %p\n", &p);
    eg(1);
    return 0;
}
```

Example run:

```
main() first variable at 0x7fffef0aaf68
#1 first variable at 0x7fffef0aaf38
#2 first variable at 0x7fffef0aaf08
#3 first variable at 0x7fffef0aaed8
```

These are just 48 bytes apart -- in other words, they are being placed one after the other contiguously (with other little bits of actual data) with no unused space between them.  If we use that in the multi-threaded program, without the nested recursion but calling `eg()` once in each thread:

```
Thread 1: top of stack near 0x7f4bd5061e78; argv_string=one
Thread 2: top of stack near 0x7f4bd4860e78; argv_string=two
Thread 3: top of stack near 0x7f4bd405fe78; argv_string=three
#3 first variable at 0x7f4bd405fe48
#1 first variable at 0x7f4bd5061e48
#2 first variable at 0x7f4bd4860e48
```

The variable for each is near the top of the three separate stacks.

All of this is in the high address region referred to as "stack space", but in a multi-threaded program, that is divided into **multiple stacks**; it is not treated as one big LIFO structure.

Comment: The pthread_create(3) man page has an example program that illustrates exactly what I was writing about. I see that I used "the stack" to represent both function activation records in a stack structure, and the (on x86) upper address space used to contain the values of the stack structure.

Comment: Not really; although in the example run the virtual addresses are equidistant, they are *not* within the stack space of either each other or the main thread.  Otherwise, you would use all of the main stack with only a few threads. The virtual address space of a process is more than just one giant stack -- the stack is a contiguous region of the address space, but "virtual address space" and "stack" are not synonymous.  There's also nothing in the specification that promises those address will be sequential or equidistant.

Comment: @BruceEdiger : I do see your point about all the stacks being in the same high address "stack space" but this does not mean all the data from all threads is placed in one big LIFO structure -- they each have an independent stack.  I've added some stuff using the `pthread_create` example to clarify this.